# Let $H,K$ be subgroups of $G$. Show: $H \trianglelefteq K \Rightarrow K\subset N_G(H)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H,K\leq G$. Show that:

$$H\trianglelefteq K\Rightarrow K\subset N_G(H).$$

How can I show that a subgroup is normal of a subgroup? For the last part, I've found a proof.

Comment: What have you found a proof of? This seems to be a one part question. Which part of it is the last part?

Comment: I've found a proof when a subgroup is a subset of a normalizer.

Comment: You mean you have found a proof of the reverse implication?

Comment: Well if you've stated the question correctly you don't care about that. You need to show that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $K$, $K$ is contained in the normalizer of $H$. Once you write down what both of these things mean the implication follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

$N_G(H) = \{g \in G : gHg^{-1} = H \}$ is by definition.
You know that $H$ is normal in $K$.  That is, for every $k \in K$, $k H k^{-1} = H$. 
What can you conclude?